# Display a photo taken from camera in a table view

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I've found a few questions similar but nothing answered my question. I want the user to select a table cell, have the camera open, take a photo, and have that photo load into the imageView in the table cell. Here is a snippet of my code so far. I'm just lost as how to add this photo into the table cell. Thanks!

```
 func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [NSObject : AnyObject]){
    imagePicker.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    var photo = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage
}

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return bedroomCells.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(textCellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

    let row = indexPath.row
    cell.textLabel?.text = bedroomCells[row]
    //cell.imageView?.image =
    return cell
}
```

Comment: You need to define a view based table view and place a NSImage cell in the column. When you dequeue it you need to place the image in that cell and it will show in the table.

Comment: I am not sure I have understood this clearly, but the way I see it is this. When a user taps on one of your tableviewcells, the didSelectRowAtIndexPath gets called, from which your camera opens up, picture taken and gets stored in your array. Then you reload the tableview and it should pick up the image from the array.

Comment: Yes, thats exactly what I'm trying to do. So best practice is to save the image taken on the camera into an array, and then retrieve that image in the cellForRowAtIndexPath?

Comment: Thomas, that's a Mac OS answer to an iOS question ;).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this out, seems to be working for me:

```
class ExampleTableViewController: UITableViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    struct TestStruct {
        var text: String?
        var image: UIImage?
    }

    var imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
    var bedroomCells = [TestStruct]()
    var lastSelectedIndex: NSIndexPath?
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        imagePicker.delegate = self
        for var i = 0; i < 10 ; i++ {
            var entry = TestStruct(text: "\(i)", image: nil)
            bedroomCells.append(entry)
        }
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return bedroomCells.count;
    }


    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("sampleCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
        cell.textLabel?.text = bedroomCells[indexPath.row].text
        cell.imageView?.image = bedroomCells[indexPath.row].image

        return cell
    }


    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        self.lastSelectedIndex = indexPath // Save the selected index
        self.presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }


    func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
        imagePicker.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
        var photo = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage
        bedroomCells[lastSelectedIndex!.row].image = photo // Set the image for the selected index
        tableView.reloadData() // Reload table view
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this sample git code, I have addressed common tableviewCell problems using Custom cell, PrepareforReuse and willDisplay cell to show image are reset when not used. 
Also this contains reusable cameraAlert which can be called from any view controller, with pick from gallery or camera capture.

https://github.com/shruezee/MultipleImage-TableViewCell-CameraCapture

Further to **muneeb** answer, removing images in prepareForReuse() helps resolving, scrolling issue. In case you have single image just make it nil. otherwise remove all from superview

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()

//        cellImageView.image = nil
        removeAllImagesFromStack()
    }

func removeAllImagesFromStack() {
    for each in imageStackview.subviews {
        if let imageviewFromStack = each as? UIImageView {
            imageviewFromStack.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    }
}
```

I also had add image button inside `tableViewCell` so added callback method to get action inside `tabView`, detail implementation inside git link

```
var addImagePressed: ((UIStackView) -> Void)?

    @IBAction func addImageButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        addImagePressed?(imageStackview)
    }
```